# Show result summary in theme table

Tags: paging, theming, forms

Can we show the result summary like "Displaying X to Y of Z records" while using the "table" or "tableselect" themes? I mean just the thing we do in views header/footer using the "Global: Result summary" option.

Hope I am clear with the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

On your theme's **template.ph**p override the **theme_pager** function as below.You need to do some HTML customization as per your need.Hope this helps.

```
function themename_pager(&$variables){

$element = $variables['element'];
global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items, $pager_limits;

$pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
$pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
$total_items = $pager_total_items[$element];
$limit = ($pager_limits[$element])?$pager_limits[$element]:10;

$start = ($pager_current-1)*$limit+1;
$end = ($pager_max != $pager_current)?$pager_current*$limit:$total_items;

$text = "$start to $end of $total_items Records";
return $text.theme_pager($variables);
}
```